# __ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, valueerror

I was trying to calculate the trends of temperature

```
ntimes, ny, nx = tempF.shape
print tempF.shape
trend = MA.zeros((ny,nx),dtype=float)

print trend.shape

for y in range (ny):
    for x in range(nx):
        trends[y,x] = numpy.polyfit(tdum, tempF[:,y,x],1)


print trend()
```

the result is

```
    (24, 241, 480)
    (241, 480)
 ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-4ac068601e48> in <module>()
     12 for y in range (0,ny):
     13     for x in range (0,nx):
---> 14         trend[y,x] = numpy.polyfit(tdum, tempF[:,y,x],1)
     15 
     16 

/home/charcoalp/anaconda2/envs/pyn_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.pyc in __setitem__(self, indx, value)
   3272         if _mask is nomask:
   3273             # Set the data, then the mask
-> 3274             _data[indx] = dval
   3275             if mval is not nomask:
   3276                 _mask = self._mask = make_mask_none(self.shape, _dtype)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I've just used python for few days, can any one help me, thank you

Comment: `numpy` routines, and thus `numpy.polyfit`, generally work vectorised: on vectors (1D, 2D, ...) at a time. So if you input an N-dim vector, you may get out an N-dim vector. Yet here, you assign it to a *single* element of `trend`. Carefully read what exactly is returned by `numpy.polyfit`. To debug, just print the return value of the `numpy.polyfit` call directly, without assigning it something. That should also help you further.

Comment: Note the vectorised application also means that generally you should avoid explicit loops (like the double for-loop here); NumPy will often do that under the hood, and tends to do that much faster than a regular (double) for-loop in Python.

Comment: `polyfit` returns a deg+1 long array.  With this call a 2 element array.  You are trying to assign that to one element of a masked-array.  Why is `trend` initialized to a masked array?  What value(s) do you expect to put in `trend`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create `ny` by `nx` zeros ndarray, you can specify, which type you want to store in it's elements. If you want to store 1x2 array of float values (polyfit with degree=1 returns 1x2 array of floats) in each cell of your zeros array, you can choose a following type instead of `float`:

```
trend = numpy.zeros((ny,nx), dtype='2f')
```

After that, you can easily store your arrays, as elements of `trend` ndarray

Comment: Or initial it as a (ny, nx, 2) array.